# opencv Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, debian, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

i'm trying to detect a face using a cascade classifier (`haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml`), but this line

```
cascade.detectMultiScale(img, vec, 1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, cv::Size(40, 40), cv::Size(125, 160));
```

gives me this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /home/rigu10/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/rigu10/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

the image `img` is a `cv::Mat` created using `imread()` and `vec` is a `vector<cv::Rect>`.
i'm woring on debian with opencv 2.4.9, but the same code works fine in macos using the same version of opencv.